# Geo redirect user just once using php

Tags: php, redirect, geoip

i can use this script easily when users land on site.com/redirect.php
they get redirected to appropriate TLD according to geo IP
but when i add this code in 'index.php' it creates a redirect loop.
Can you help me modify it so that it doesn't create loop. right now this 'break' is not helping..

```
<?php
// Next two lines are for Beyond Hosting
// Don't forget to change your-domain
require_once '/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.dat');

// Next two lines are for HostGator
require_once 'Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('GeoIP.dat');

try {
  $country = $geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  switch((string)$country) {
    case 'AU':
      $url = "http://www.site.au";
      break;
    case 'CA':
      $url = "http://www.site.ca";
      break;
    default:
      $url = "http://site.com";
  }

  header('Location: '.$url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Handle exception
}
?>
```

Comment: It's an infinite loop, cause you're redirecting them constantly to the index page, the page checks in which country they are and then redirects them to index page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the user is visiting the site via the localised URL before forwarding:

```
<?php
// Next two lines are for Beyond Hosting
// Don't forget to change your-domain
require_once '/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('/home/your-domain/php/Net/GeoIP.dat');

// Next two lines are for HostGator
require_once 'Net/GeoIP.php';
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance('GeoIP.dat');

try {
  $country = $geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  switch((string)$country) {
    case 'AU':
      $url = "http://www.site.au";
      break;
    case 'CA':
      $url = "http://www.site.ca";
      break;
    default:
      $url = "http://site.com";
  }

  if (strpos("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]", $url) === false)
  {
      header('Location: '.$url);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Handle exception
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Where did you get the GeoIP.php file?

Answer (score 0):

```
use this  
header("Location:".$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like: (WARNING, i haven't tested this code, but the logic should be like this)

```
//Inside your try:
$country = $geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$serverName = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$serverCountryCode = $serverName[count($serverName)-1];
if (strtoupper ($serverCountryCode) != $country)) {
$shouldRedirect = true;
switch((string)$country) {
    case 'AU':
      $url = "http://www.site.au";
      break;
    case 'CA':
      $url = "http://www.site.ca";
      break;
    default:
      if ($serverCountryCode == 'com') {
        $shouldRedirect = false;
      }
      $url = "http://site.com";
  }
  if ($shouldRedirect) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
  }
}
```